# When did modern medicine begin?

Tags: medical-history

What is the conventionally accepted time period in which modern medicine began and are there any discoveries that are considered to be particularly relevant?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the History exchange.

Comment: @CareyGregory I think that should be debated. We do have the tag [tag:history-of-medicine], the only problem I see is that *modern medicine* isn’t a technical name for a branch of medicine. Unlike *modern literature* or *postmodernism*, it’s just a label and not a defined era.

Comment: According to [MedicalNewsToday](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/info/medicine/modern-medicine.php) they consider history from the 19th century onwards to be modern medicine.  The article also covers a lot of the milestones up to the present day.

Comment: Whether it fits here, on History:SE, or History of Science and Math: what has your research shown you so far?

Comment: @Chris - While I don't think there is enough room to detail all of them, that definition and some of the biggest milestones would make a good answer. (artificial heart, saline solution, etc.)